# Access store in grid panel Extjs

Tags: extjs

This could be a stupid question, but I cant figure out how to access store in gridpanel

```
  var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    .....
    store: store,
    ......
      listeners: {
        'beforerender' : function(grid) {
          //grid.getStore();
            }
           }
```

I want to loop through the store , but grid.getStore() returns empty object.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply do `grid.store`.

If you know it will be filled with data before the grid renders (you seem to be calling this from the grid `beforerender` event) you can do `grid.store.getRange()` to get the records that you want to loop through, as you mentioned in your question.

Comment: It looks like the call to load the store is make after  afterrender event, is that possible ?

Comment: Yes that is normally the sequence, if you are using ajax to get the store data, the grid will render before the data loads. I assumed you were creating a grid sometime after page initialization and that was why you were trying to do this in the `beforerender` event. As I understand, you are trying to iterate through the records of the store, I would add a listener in the store on the load event (which fires once the data loads) then put your iteration functionality in there.

Answer (score 0):

**store** variable is still visible in your listener code :)

Comment: e-zinc has a good point, it seems your problem is with the fact that you are running this in the `beforerender` event and the store has not loaded. See my comment below.